# Customize MUI Gridtoolbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, customization

I'm using MUI Datagrid and i wanna know if there is a way to customize the gridtoolbar with custom buttons and text.

Thanks.

Federico

[image: This is the toolbar i wanna customize]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I imagine that you know, thak to enable the toolbar you need to add the `Toolbar: GridToolbar` to the grid components prop - like

```
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  components={{
    Toolbar: GridToolbar,
  }}
/>
```

So, if you want to custom, and add others things, you must compose your own toolbar, for example:

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}
```

And do the same thing:

```
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  components={{
    Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
  }}
/>
```

Source: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#toolbar

Answer (score 5):

The components prop is depricated. Now, you can do:

```
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  slots={{
    toolbar: CustomToolbar,
  }}
/>
```

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}
```